# Left align text within alignat and keep everything else centered

Tags: math-mode, alignat

I know there are lots of questions out there about "left align using alignat". But so far I haven't figured out a solution to this. I am using `\begin{alignat}{2}` and want to make a piece of `\text{..}` left-aligned (i.e. flush with the left hand margin) but keep the rest of the equation centered. How can I achieve this?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
a_1 &= b_1 &&= c_1 
\\
\text{and} a_{111} &= b_{111} &&= c_{111}.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

*UPDATE*

I understand that using either `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` are options, but, I have lots of other equations written using `flalign` for which I am able to get "and" on the same line. So I was hoping I could keep the formatting consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three other possibilities, with `flalign + alignedat`, or with `fleqn` (from `nccmath`) + `align` + `\makebox*` (from `makebox`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{makebox}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
 & \text{and} &&\begin{alignedat}[b]{2} a_1 &= b_{1} & & = c_1 \\
 a_{111} &= b_{111} & & = c_{111}.
\end{alignedat} & &
\end{flalign}
\vskip 3ex
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}
&& a_1 &= \makebox*{$b_{111}$}[l]{$ b_{1} $} = c_1 \\
 & \text{and} & a_{111} &= b_{111} = c_{111}.
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\vskip 3ex
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}
&& a_1 &= \makebox*{$b_{111}$}[l]{$ b_{1} $} = c_1 & & \\
 & \text{and} & a_{111} &= b_{111} = c_{111}. & &
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

with `flalign` and some manual tweaking using `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
            && a_1       &= b_{1\hphantom{11}} = c_1      &    \\
\text{and}  && a_{111}   &= b_{111}            = c_{111}. &
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm upvoting because your answer is clearly superior to my own.  Bravo!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thank you very much. i liked your second example (+1).

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, this is indeed a very neat solution to this specific problem. But... unfortunately, the equations I am dealing with on the two different lines are very unrelated to each other. `b_1` and `b_{111}` are conveniently very similar to each other. Maybe my mistake for choosing a very simple MWE ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this approach needs to be manually tuned.  It uses added negative space with the `\\[-33pt]` and then applies a `\smash`ed version of `\intertext` which itself has been lowered.

EDITED to put the shenanigans in a `\vbox`, so that it becomes immune to vertical compression based on page density.  Note, however, that the `\vbox` will now cause spacing before and after the equations to be different, as well, though perhaps one can find a compromise.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
Leading text
\\\vbox{\begin{alignat}{2}
a_1 &= b_1 &&= c_1 
\\[-33pt]
\intertext{\smash{\raisebox{-27pt}{and}}} 
a_{111} &= b_{111} &&= c_{111}.
\end{alignat}}
trailing text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a `stackengine` alternative that only makes you guess a single number to match the line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
Leading text\\
\setbox0=\vbox{\begin{alignat}{2}
a_1 &= b_1 &&= c_1 
\\
a_{111} &= b_{111} &&= c_{111}.
\end{alignat}}
\noindent\stackengine{17pt}{\box0}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{and}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}
trailing text
\end{document}
```

Of course, the more probable advice you will get is to just use `\intertext` in the normally prescribed way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
a_1 &= b_1 &&= c_1 
\\
\intertext{and}
a_{111} &= b_{111} &&= c_{111}.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The manual method does work I guess, but it doesn't play well when the linespacing is adjusted. Maybe I will have to compromise.

Comment: @Milo You can preclude the linespacing change by putting the `alignat` in a `\vbox`, though this will naturally change other things.  See my edit.